# How to delete row of GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have code that adds rows to a GridBagLayout, but I can't figure out how to remove one. I want to get rid of the last row of the layout when a certain button is clicked.

This is the code that adds them:

```
public static JPanel createLayout(int rows) {
    JPanel product = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    String[] lables = {"School    ", "Advanced #", "Novice #   "};
    double weight = .3333333333333;

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
    c.weightx = weight;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridy = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < lables.length; j++) {
        c.gridx = j;
        JLabel l = new JLabel(lables[j]);
        product.add(l, c);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        c.gridy++;
        for (int j = 0; j < lables.length; j++) {
            c.gridx = j;
            JTextField f = new JTextField();
            product.add(f, c);
        }
    }
    c.gridy++;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    JPanel b = new JPanel();
    JButton add = new JButton("+");
    b.add(add);
    JButton delete = new JButton("-");
    b.add(delete);
    product.add(b, c);
    return product;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Debate Calculator");
    JPanel debates = new JPanel();
    frame.add(createLayout(5), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

So how do I delete a row?

Comment: Use a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), this is what it's designed for

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on doing it all yourself, you're going to need to maintain some kind of model so you know where everything is.

Start by adding each row of components to some kind of `List`.  When you delete a row, you could simply find all the components that make up that row and remove them from the container.

This presents you with a problem.  Because the `y` position of the last row may longer match the number of rows.  (ie, you can not simply do `c.gridy = listOfComponents.size()` to determine where to add the next row).

`GridBagConstraints` does, however, allow you to obtain the constraints used to layout a given component.  This means you could find the last row in the `list`, get the constraints for the first column and you would be able to deduce the last `y` position...Take a look at [`GridBagConstraints#getConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getConstraints%28java.awt.Component%29) for more info.

Or you could just use a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Thanks for the more complex answer for cases where JTable fails to satisfy complex requirements!